# How can I find a find a match in a list of values, rounded down to the nearest match, in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm aware of the ABS and Round functions in SQL Server but I believe my problem is a little different and I'm not sure how to use these to achieve the desired result.

Say I have a number: 8000

And I have a query that returns this list of numbers: 0, 5000, 10000, 15000

If I use the ABS function with this list e.g

```
DECLARE @target as INT
SET @target = 8000
SELECT TOP(1) @result AS Number
FROM dbo.Numbers
ORDER BY ABS(Number - @target)
```

I get 10000

Which is expected

But how can I make this return 5000 i.e. I always get the result rounded down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding your question to mean you want the nearest match without going over:

Add a `WHERE Number <= @target`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
WHERE Number <= @target
ORDER BY Number DESC
```

We simply get the first number (`ORDER BY Number DESC`) not greater than the @target (`WHERE Number <= @target`).

The nice thing about losing `ABS` in `ORDER BY` this is that the DBMS should now be able to utilize an index on `Number` (if there is one).